# schedule a job to run only "once" after 50 seconds

Tags: unix, cron

I have a process which is designed to do a specific task in case of events.
Requirement is to run a specific command 50 seconds after an event occurs.

Cannot modify the code to put sleep there as it would block the process flow.

Can it be done via cron or any other unix commands?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a bash script, start it with "sleep 50s" and then call the program or command you wnat to run.

Comment: That's one way of doing it. Is there way of scheduling a job?

Comment: If the simple way of doing it is enough, why try to make it more complex ? KISS principle applies. (This hints to me you aren't explaining properly what you actually want to do).

Comment: This is what i wanted to do. But didn't actually feel right. My process will launching a script which in turn will be launching this script to run after ~50 seconds. Too many script calls. If i am able to configure a cron, then all i need to do is set the cron and let system handle it itself.

Comment: Well, you can use the [at](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_at.htm) command to schedule a task to run at a specific time if it makes you feel better.

Comment: in that case ill have to first calculate the time after 50 seconds and  then run the at command. rt? or i can specify the at command to run after ~50 secs?